# Postgres using ORDER BY on an AVG function

Tags: sql-order-by, psql

I am new to Postgres, and I am trying to join tables, get average values and order by average values. The 2 tables are described below:

```
Table "public.movies"
   Column    |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 movieid     | integer | not null  | plain    |              | 
 title       | text    |           | extended |              | 
 releasedate | date    |           | plain    |              | 
 url         | text    |           | extended |              | 
 unknown     | integer |           | plain    |              | 
 action      | integer |           | plain    |              | 
 adventure   | integer |           | plain    |              | 
 animation   | integer |           | plain    |              | 
 children    | integer |           | plain    |              | 
 comedy      | integer |           | plain    |              | 
 crime       | integer |           | plain    |              | 
 documentary | integer |           | plain    |              | 
 drama       | integer |           | plain    |              | 



Table "public.ratings"
 Column  |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description 
---------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 userid  | integer | not null  | plain   |              | 
 movieid | integer | not null  | plain   |              | 
 rating  | integer |           | plain   |              | 
 time    | integer |           | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "ratings_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (userid, movieid)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "ratings_movieid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (movieid) REFERENCES movies(movieid)
Has OIDs: no
```

I have to order by the average ratings as one movieid has multiple ratings from different users, but I have to order by (asc) the average ratings. My query is as below,  and works fine without ORDER BY:

```
 SELECT (movies.title, AVG(ratings.rating)) 
 FROM movies 
    FULL JOIN ratings ON movies.movieid = ratings.movieid 
 WHERE (movies.comedy = 1) GROUP BY movies.title LIMIT 10;
```

It however returns 1.00000000000 for ALL the movie ratings if I use: `ORDER BY AVG(ratings.rating)`

Any help will be really appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: do **not** put parenthesis around the columns in your select list. It's totally useless and especially in Postgres it will return something different than you intend. `select a,b` is something different than `select (a,b)`.

Answer (score 4):

To order by an aggregate you need to either use a subquery, or use an ordinal position for the order-specifier.

In the following I have:

- changed your `FULL JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - it doesn't make sense for a rating to exist without a `movieid`, and if it did, it would be useless as it'd appear in this query as an average rating for movieid `null`.
- Added `ORDER BY 2` to tell Pg to sort by the average column

Resulting in:

```
 SELECT movies.title, AVG(ratings.rating)
 FROM movies 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ratings ON movies.movieid = ratings.movieid 
 WHERE (movies.comedy = 1)
 GROUP BY movies.title
 ORDER BY 2
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your time :) However, the 2 tables movies and ratings have different columns (in the qn above). So, what happens to the rows 'userid', 'rating' and 'time' if we only do left outer join. That is why I used 'full join' because then those rows will have an empty row added to table movies. Does  it make sense?

Comment: @student001 If I understand you correctly, you appear to be confusing outer and inner joins. A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` adds a `NULL` set of columns to the *right* side if no match for the join condition is found. A `FULL OUTER JOIN` does the same, but *also* adds `NULL` on the *left* side if there's a row on the *right* that doesn't match. That makes no sense for your data model - how can you have a rating without a movie? If you want to show movies without ratings (as rating `null`) you want a `left outer join`. If you want *only movies that have one or more ratings* you want an `inner join`.